# Pandas: Find top 10 combination of records in one column, based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of 2 columns. First is order_id, Second is item_name. I want the top 10 choice of combination of Items based on order_id

Data looks like

```
order_id    Item_Name
1   A
1   B
1   C
1   D
2   A
2   B
2   D
2   E
2   B
2   C
3   D
3   E
3   F
3   G
3   A
3   B
4   F
4   D
4   A
4   B
4   C
```

I want the top combinations ranked and separated by pipes like

1. A|B|D
2. B|D|E

The combinations can be for any number of Item_Name Numbers

Comment: What does "top 10 choice" mean? What have you tried ?

Comment: top 10 choice means what are the most popular combinations of items purchased by order

Comment: I thought of using pivot, but I am kind of stuck with the solution.

Comment: I can't understand your question .Can explain it with an example.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
n=10
df.groupby('order_id').i.value_counts().groupby('order_id').head(n).astype(str).reset_index(name='v').groupby('order_id').i.agg('|'.join)
```

Comment: Is i in here supposed to be Item_name?

Comment: @ArpitAcharya yes

Comment: So it, did not provide me the top 10 combination. The head(n) doesnt seem to work on something like a sorted value_counts. Just to be clear if Order 1 has A,B,C,D and Order 2 has A,B,C,E. A valid combination between the 2 is A,B,C